# Make an image scales to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, object-fit

Considering the following code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;

  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;

  padding: 10px;

  background: red;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
}
.box img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
  <figure class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
  </figure>
</div>
```

I would expect `object-fit: contain` to make the `img` shrink into the `.box`, automatically sized by the flex container. Instead of my expectation, it overflows from the box. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.box` should be `display:flex` too so that the img can "grow" within the `.box`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
  <figure class="box">
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
  </figure>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/k0gsZbwwRq

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is also part of the magic, since it prevents the `.box` to be scaled by the `img`, isnt' it?

Comment: yes. and the `display:flex` helps the image to maintain ratio so it doesn't get clipped inside the box.